# How to get XPath of an element when it is in sub tab (Salesforce Lightning component)

Tags: selenium, xpath, salesforce, lightning

In the following snippets, [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) for the drop down element in last column of accounts table is similar in [Subtab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6iox.jpg) and [Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A44Oc.jpg).

I am using the XPath expression

```
//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/span/div/a[2][@role="button"]
```

to click on drop down element. But unable to do so as it happens to appear in the previous page too.

Please help me in identifying unique irrespective of tabs.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPATH :- `(//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/span/div/a[2][@role="button"])[1]`